# Memory Leak due to Exception in End Invoke

Tags: .net, remoting

I am using .Net Remoting for sending objects between two servers.
The objects are sent by "Begin Invoke" mechanism as required in such case I use EndInvoke, but the following exception consistently thrown during the End Invoke:

```
System.Net.WebExceptionSystem.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond …
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpClientTransportSink.AsyncHttpClientRequestState.ProcessGetRequestStreamCompletion(IAsyncResult iar)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Core.Common.CLSAPI.EventArrivedHandler.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
```

After some hours my application crashes due to "Out Of Memory Exception" and from the dump file I can see that all the objects that I tried to send still be referenced by one of the remoting objects therefore still not collected by the GC.
What is the right way to handle exception in EndInvoke to avoid memory leak?

I understand that this problem might be caused/fixed by some changes on the client side, nevertheless it is important for me to understand which changes can I do on the server side to assure robustness of my server.

Comment: Can you show us the code in question?

Comment: This is the kind of OOM you get from using unmanaged resources (like sockets and threads) but never allocating enough managed memory to get the garbage collector running to clean up.

Comment: It looks like you are doing an HttpWebRequest on the server-side. Did I get that right? If yes, please post the code where you do that (and where you Dispose of the resources).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your replies. Here is the code: sending the object , while the object sent is eventData: try { ... AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(SendEventResultCallback); m_eEvent.BeginInvoke(obj, eventData, callback, null); LogManager.Instance().(...) } catch (SerializationException se) { ...}\

Comment: result callback code:
 
public static void SendEventResultCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
  try
            {
                LogManager.Instance().Debug("SendEventResultCallback was called!");
                AsyncResult aResult = (AsyncResult)ar;
                EventArrivedHandler temp = (EventArrivedHandler)aResult.AsyncDelegate;
                temp.EndInvoke(ar);
                LogManager.Instance().Debug("SendEventResultCallback was finished!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
   ...
            }
        }